# How to set Horizontal Recyclerview in one of the fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android

I m having a ViewPager with three fragments , one fragment has something that scrolls horizontally but when m trying to scroll it slides the page

Comment: what have you tried? please post your code

Answer (score 0):

if you need a horizontal RecyclerView you just need to add a the RecyclerView to your fragment and use `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

**OR**

---

just add this `RecyclerView` in your fragment

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Comment: My question is how to set in ViewPager as i scroll RecyclerView it is scrolling ViewPager Screen